# Правильное использование унаследованных классов

Tags: c++, наследование

У меня есть проблема, с которой я борюсь уже 2 дня. Проблема заключается в том, что мне нужно написать логику для получения настроек мультимедиа из унаследованного класса. Чтобы полностью понять, что именно я хочу реализовать, приведу краткий пример.

У меня есть интерфейс:

```cpp
class MediaSettings
{
public:

    MediaSettings(QString mediaType);
    MediaSettings& operator=(const MediaSettings& other) = delete;
    MediaSettings& operator=(MediaSettings&& other)      = delete;
    MediaSettings(const MediaSettings& other)            = delete;
    MediaSettings(MediaSettings&& other)                 = delete;
    virtual ~MediaSettings()                             = default;

    QString getType() { return m_mediaType; }

    virtual bool isSupported() const noexcept = 0;

protected:

    QString m_mediaType{ "UNK" };
};
```

И два класса, которые содержут в себе определенные поля настроек мультимедиа, а именно класс **AudioSettings** и **VideoSettings**.

**AudioSettings**:

```cpp
class AudioSettings : public MediaSettings
{
public:

    explicit AudioSettings(const int32_t& bitRate, const int32_t& sampleRate, const int32_t& channelCount, const QString& audioCodec)
        : MediaSettings("audio")
    {
        
    }

    AudioSettings& operator=(const AudioSettings& other) = default;
    AudioSettings& operator=(AudioSettings&& other)      = default;
    AudioSettings(const AudioSettings& other)            = default;
    AudioSettings(AudioSettings&& other)                 = default;
    virtual ~AudioSettings()                             = default;

    bool operator==(const AudioSettings& other) const noexcept;
    bool operator!=(const AudioSettings& other) const noexcept;

    void setChannelCount(const int32_t& channelCount) noexcept;
    void setSampleRate(const int32_t& sampleRate) noexcept;
    void setAudioCodec(const QString& audioCodec) noexcept;
    void setBitRate(const int32_t& bitRate) noexcept;

    int32_t channelCount() const noexcept;
    QString audioCodec() const noexcept;
    int32_t sampleRate() const noexcept;
    int32_t bitRate() const noexcept;

    virtual bool isSupported() const noexcept override;

protected:

    int32_t m_bitRate{ -1 };
    int32_t m_sampleRate{ -1 };
    int32_t m_channelCount{ -1 };
    QString m_audioCodec;

};
```

**VideoSettings**:

```cpp
class VideoSettings : public MediaSettings
{
public:

    explicit VideoSettings(const int32_t& width, const int32_t& height, const QString& videoCodec)
        : MediaSettings("video")
    {
        
    }

    VideoSettings& operator=(const VideoSettings& other) = default;
    VideoSettings& operator=(VideoSettings&& other)      = default;
    VideoSettings(const VideoSettings& other)            = default;
    VideoSettings(VideoSettings&& other)                 = default;
    virtual ~VideoSettings()                             = default;

    bool operator==(const VideoSettings& other) const noexcept;
    bool operator!=(const VideoSettings& other) const noexcept;

    int32_t width() const noexcept;
    int32_t height() const noexcept;
    QString videoCodec() const noexcept;
    
    void setWidth(const int32_t& width) noexcept;
    void setHeight(const int32_t& height) noexcept;
    void setVideoCodec(const QString& videoCodec) noexcept;
    
    virtual bool isSupported() const noexcept override;

protected:

    int32_t m_width{ -1 };
    int32_t m_height{ -1 };
    QString m_videoCodec;

};
```

И вот тут-то и возникает моя главная проблема. У меня есть класс `MediaRecorder`, который имеет метод установки медиа настроек:

```cpp
class MediaRecorder
{
public:

    MediaRecorder();
    virtual ~MediaRecorder();
    
    bool record(const MediaData data);
    bool start();
    bool stop();
    
    void setMediaSettings(MediaSettings* settings) noexcept;
    
    // Какие-то функции
    
protected:
    
    // Какие-то параметры

    MediaSettings* p_settings;
};
```

И в этом классе есть параметры, которые, в свою очередь, могут одновременно ожидать как настройки звука, так и настройки видео. В качестве примера, при установке аудио настроек, данный рекордер должен работать с методами, описанными в классе **AudioSettings**:

```cpp
// main.cpp
// Создаем рекордер
MediaRecorder recorder;

// Устанавливаем ему настройки для аудио
recorder.setMediaSettings(new AudioSettings(64000, 8000, 1, "alaw"));
```

реализация метола **setMediaSettings**:

```cpp
void MediaRecorder::setMediaSettings(MediaSettings* settings) noexcept
{
    if (settings) {
        if (settings.getType() == "audio") {
            auto audioSettings = reinterpret_cast<AudioSettings>(settings);
            // Работаем с методами AudioSettings
            int bitrate = audioSettings.bitRate();
            // ...
        }
        else if (settings.getType() == "video") {
            auto videoSettings = reinterpret_cast<VideoSettings>(settings);
            // Работаем с методами AudioSettings
            int width = videoSettings.width();
            // ...
        }
        else {
            // Error
        }
    }
}
```

Правильно ли реализована логика определения типа наследуемого класса ? А если нет, то не могли бы вы объяснить мне, как это правильно реализовать?

Comment: Непонятно, зачем вам тут понадобилась иерархия классов, если MediaRecorder все равно обращается к конкретному типу.

Comment: @user7860670 Это всего лишь пример того, как бы мне хотелось использовать определенные методы унаследоваемого класса.  По сути, моя проблема заключается в том, что я не могу просто объединить параметры аудио и видео настроек в 1 класс. Поэтому у меня есть общий интерфейс. Но при создание определенный настроек, хотелось бы реализовать логику работы не только с методами интерфейса, но и с частными методами.

Comment: Ну так не объединяйте их в один класс. Оставьте два отдельных класса. Ведь единственное, что их объединяет в приведенном интерфейсе - это метод `isSupported`. И сделайте две перегрузки `setMediaSettings`.

Comment: Согласен, но в данном случае, мне придется добавить два метода в классе `MediaRecorder`, для установки аудио и видео настроек.

Comment: Ну и правильно - это же будет проще, чем городить `if (settings.getType() == "video") {  auto videoSettings = reinterpret_cast<VideoSettings>(settings);` Каст кстати совсем неправильный - справа же указатель, а классы - из одной иерархии.

Comment: Вы правы. На счет каста, я сделал это, что бы можно было получить доступ к методам видео настроек (я думал, что это возможно).

Answer (score 0):

Если уж базовый класс является интерфейсным(абстрактный), то перенесите интерфейс в базовый класс,  а в производных переопределите те функции_члены, которые нужны этому классу, тогда можете через указатель на базовый класс вызвать функцию указываемого объекта. Первоначально это может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
class MediaSettings
{
    //...
public:      
    virtual bool isSupported() const noexcept = 0;
    virtual int32_t bitRate()  const noexcept { return 0; }
    virtual int32_t width() const noexcept    { return 0; }
    virtual int32_t height() const noexcept   { return 0; }    
    //...
    bool is_audio{}; //если вам нужно
};

class AudioSettings : public MediaSettings
{
    //...
public:
    AudioSettings() { is_audio = true; } //если вам нужен был is_audio
    //...
    int32_t bitRate()  const noexcept override { //...  }
    virtual bool isSupported() const noexcept  { //... }
    //...
};

class VideoSettings : public MediaSettings
{
    //...
public:   
    int32_t width() const noexcept override{ //... }
    int32_t height() const noexcept override { //... }
    bool isSupported() const noexcept  { //...  }   
    //...
};

class MediaRecorder
{
//...
public: 
    void setMediaSettings(MediaSettings* settings) noexcept
    {
        int32_t bitrate{}, width{};
        if (settings) {
            bitrate = settings->bitRate();
            width = settings->width();
            if (bitrate /* или settings->is_audio */) {                
                // Работаем с методами AudioSettings                
            }
            else if (width) {                
                // Работаем с методами VideoSettings           
               
            }            
        }
    }

    // ...    
};
```

Comment: В данной реализации, в `MediaSettings` уже присутствуют параметры для аудио и для видео настроек. Моя же идея подразумевает разграничивание данных параметром. Все таки, я думаю, что рекомендации @user7860670 больше всего подходят в моей реализации (рекомендации заключаются в том, что бы просто перегрузить функцию установки настроек для видеи и для аудио)